# Portable way to run a simple script at startup

Tags: startup, init, portability

I'm trying to run a script at startup as root.

(Just sets up a root-owned directory in */tmp*).

Currently, I'm using this script to set up the boot hook and it appears to get the job done:

```
#!/bin/sh -eu
if [ 0 -eq $((${1:-0})) ]; then
    #install
    [ -x /etc/init.d/tmpsetup ] ||  {
        cat > /etc/init.d/tmpsetup <<'EOF'
#!/bin/sh -eu
[ $(id -u) -eq 0 ]
umask 0222
mkdir -p /tmp/u/
EOF
        chmod a+rx /etc/init.d/tmpsetup
        update-rc.d tmpsetup defaults 99
        }
else
    #uninstall
        rm -f /etc/init.d/tmpsetup
        update-rc.d tmpsetup remove
fi
```

Is there a more portable/better way to do it?

(It's to implement a /tmp per user feature. Should be part of an install script that adapts an existing system.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would've just put this into `/etc/rc.local` instead:

```
umask 0222 && mkdir -p /tmp/u/
```

Making a service around this seems like it's over complicating things.

Comment: Thanks. I want to be able to graft this onto an existing system without causing clashes, though (In actuality, all the filenames are namespaced but I removed the namespace before posting). This looks like a file only local admins should be writing into.

Comment: @PSkocik - this file is meant for modifications that are system specific. The introduction of this `/tmp/u` directory for the root user would qualify under that, IMO. Unless I'm missing something. Perhaps expand your Q?